# How to regex fix incomplete polygon

Tags: regex, polygon

```
[[106.00,-50.00],[109.00,-34.00],[101.00,-29.00],[105.00,-26.00],
    [116.00,-30.00],[114.00,-50.00] ]
```

Sample above does not draw a polygon, since start and end coordinates do not match always. How do I programmatically fix this.

And not all polygons are this length. Polygons could have more or less coordinates.

I wanted to get starting group ($1) and add this to end, if it does not match.
My regex sample is here, But I cant figure out how to get the second group. (ie last coordinates)

https://regex101.com/r/mFWVle/1

Below is expected end result, after regex and replace ;)

```
[[106.00,-50.00],[109.00,-34.00],[101.00,-29.00],[105.00,-26.00],
[116.00,-30.00],[114.00,-50.00],[106.00,-50.00] ]
```

Comment: You have delimiter syntax to find the extent of the polygon, you shouldn't need to worry about if the final point matches the first point unless you're validating. If you need to get this into an array for something, this can easily be done using the `\G` construct. Once you get this into an array, you can always rewrite the polygon item.

Comment: What tool/language are you using?  Where could the spaces appear?  We need to know this in order to answer the question.

Comment: Im getting this as json, and for me to fix it, I am using php for regex portion. On my sample I did copy/paste live portion, and you can see it has space between last "] ]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex for a valid polygon, i.e. one for which the starting and ending coordinates are the same:

```
^\[(\[-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?,-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\])(?:,\[-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?,-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\])+,$1\]$
```

### Demo

This pattern just matches and captures the first coordinate, then it asserts that this same coordinate appears as the final coordinate in the polygon definition.

I assume here that there are no spaces in the polygon definition.  If there could be arbitrary whitespace, we could update the regex to cope with that, but honestly it might be cleaner to just strip all whitespace and then use the above pattern as is.

**Edit:**

If instead you want to match a polygon and replace by *adding* the first coordinate to the end, and there could also be spaces in between coordinates, then find on this pattern:

```
^\[(\[-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?,-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\])((?:\s*,\s*\[-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?,-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\])+)\]$
```

and replace with this:

```
$1$2,$1
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. My sample is "live" sample, and it does include space char towards the end, as I listed. Also, I should have been more clear, that first coordinate, needs to be added at the end behind 114.00,-50.00 . This data comes from gov data, and believe or not but someone did not complete the polygon. Im trying to fix this until they fix their systems to perform this check.

Comment: @Ossi This may not be an _exact_ pattern for all your data, but I think you should easily enough be able to take what I gave above and adapt it.  Cheers.